# Excel - Conditionally fill cell with date but remain static after fill

Tags: excel, date, formula

I'm trying to fill a cell with today's date when data is entered by a user in another cell. This is working fine, but my problem is the date is 'volatile', meaning it updates to today's date every time the spreadsheet is opened after that. I've was using `=TODAY()` originally but then discovered the problem on day two when I opened the spreadsheet and read that `=TODAY()` is a  volatile command. I tried changing this to `=NOW()` but after opening the spreadsheet again today the same thing happened.

I know there are key strokes to turn a variable cell into a static one, but I really need something that will do this automatically and not require anyone to do extra steps. Preferably no VBA please!

The formula in the cell currently is `IF(B3="","",NOW())`. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible without VBA. Formulas will always be reevaluated and they cannot write to another cell. Recalculation could theoretically be disabled, but this would be global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static date (today) can be achieved with the keyboard shortcut

> CTRL+; (semicolon)

This would be fast, although not automatic.

As others have mentioned, VBA is probably the way to go, as globally disabling automatic calculations is far from optimal for a number of reasons.

Code can be copied from here (very little VBA knowledge requirred):
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1895-excel-record-date-and-time-when-cell-changes.html

Comment: Because the VBA was so easy to use and adapt to my needs I'm going to accept this as the answer. Thank you!